# Can I update my model using partial_fit after training my model using fit?

Tags: machine-learning-model, pickle

I have trained my model using MLPClassifier using `fit` method and saving in `pickle` object for the first time.

```
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,50,5), max_iter=100, alpha=0.0001,
                     solver='sgd', verbose=10,  random_state=21,tol=0.000000001)
clf.fit(X_old, y_old)
joblib.dump(clf, 'saved_model_clf.pkl')
```

After few hours I am getting new data from online and I am updating my model using `partial_fit` .

```
clf_load = joblib.load('saved_model_clf.pkl')
y_new = to_categorical(y_new,num_classes=3) #I knew classes from training set
clf_load.partial_fit(X_new, y_new, classes=list(range(y_new.shape[1])))
joblib.dump(clf_load, 'saved_model_clf.pkl')
```

After `partial_fit` I'm `predict`ing my results

```
clf_pred = joblib.load('saved_model_clf.pkl')
predictions = clf_pred.predict(df[0:1])
```

I found that my model is not learning on new incoming data while performing Prediction after the `partial_fit`

I am not sure where is the mistake

Case 1:
I am doing mistake in saving and retrieving pickle object .

Case 2:
My assumption of updating my model is wrong .

Can someone help me out to solve my problem please ?

Example dataset for `clf.fit`

```
X_old = {"TABLE":"XYZ","MODULE":"ABY", "MAX_TIME":647,"RESPONSE":"SUCCESS","SEVERITY":"Critical", "SERVICE":"ZC Service", "EVENT_NAME":"SendEmail"}

Y_old = {"Classification":"Ignore_Anyway"}
```

Example dataset for `clf.partial_fit`

```
X_new = {"TABLE":"XYZ","MODULE":"ABY", "MAX_TIME":647,"RESPONSE":"SUCCESS","SEVERITY":"Critical", "SERVICE":"ZC Service", "EVENT_NAME":"SendEmail"}

Y_new = {"Classification":"Not_Ignore"}
```

Comment: How do you now the model is not learning on the new data ? Also, be careful when putting `classes=list(range(y_new.shape[1]))` if not all classes are in the new data.

Comment: I am passing X_old in```clf.fit``` with ```Ignore_Anway``` class and after few hours when I am updating using```clf.partial_fit``` with X_new with same Scenario (X_feature values) with different class ```Not_Ignore``` . When I am predicting for same Scenario of X_new , the predicted calss is ```Ignore_Anway``` always predicts the ```clf.fit``` method classes even after updating my model with different class.```Note: I have splited my dataset into two half for fit and partial_fit```. Thanks @Elliot